# Example of del Pezzo surface with positive first Betti number

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

My apologies for the ignorant question:

> What is the simplest del Pezzo surface with positive first Betti number?

I'm looking for a nice concrete example to play with.

Thanks.

Comment: All smooth Fano varieties satisfy $b_1=0$. By Kodaira vanishing $H^{i}(X, \mathcal{O}) = H^{i}(X,K_X + (-K_{X})) = 0$ for all $i > 0$. But then by Hodge theory $h^{1,0}(X) = h^{1}(X,\mathcal{O})$, hence $b_{1}(X) = 2h^{1,0}(X)=0$. 

In general it has been proven that smooth Fanos are simply connected. That is harder, one can either use Mori theory or Yau's solution of the Calabi conjecture.

Comment: Log del Pezzo surfaces are known to be simply connected also, see Lemma 1.3 here https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/journal/pdf/jms010104.pdf